# Difference between using a class vs. function for "App" in React Native

Tags: react-native

What is the difference between using this format

```
export default function App(){
    return(
    ....
}
```

and

```
export default class App extends React.Component{
    render()
    ...
}
```

??

Comment: there is no difference... I used both and both worked well... Actually I'm using extends React.Component because I used a Context directly in App, and I preferred to have a state to share with Context

Answer (score 1):

Being as honest as possible I use functions for styling since they are easier to debug and test. Class have the props and states so they are better suited for development of items that need all the extra parts such as props from the hierarchy since it is extended by "Component".